# Oracle conversion from SQL Server - WeekRange Based on Date

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, date, date-conversion

I need help converting some SQL Server code to Oracle.

This relates to selecting the week range based on a date.

**SQL Server Example**

```
select 
    (CONVERT(Varchar(8)
    , (dateadd(dd,(datediff(dd,0,getdate())/7)*7,0)), 1)) + ' - ' +                                         
    (CONVERT(Varchar(8)
    , (dateadd(dd,((datediff(dd,0,getdate())/7)*7)+6,0)), 1))   WeekRange
```

*Results*

WeekRange = 09/14/20 - 09/20/20

**Today's Actual Date**

09/18/20

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That would be something like this:

```
SQL> select to_char(trunc(sysdate, 'iw')    , 'mm/dd/yy') || ' - ' ||
  2         to_char(trunc(sysdate, 'iw') + 6, 'mm/dd/yy') result
  3  from dual;

RESULT
-------------------
09/14/20 - 09/20/20

SQL>
```

Comment: It (iw) is a format model mask which returns *week of year*.